# THREE.Path usage and example

Tags: three.js

I'm trying to figure out how to draw a simple Path using [threejs](/questions/tagged/threejs). I found no example anywhere (the ones moving the camera through a path, but not the ones drawing the path).

What I need to archive is to draw a straight line and at the end of this, draw a spline curve.

Using for example those points:

```
<!-- language: lang-js -->
var v1 = new THREE.Vector2(2754, -4996); //init straight line
var v2 = new THREE.Vector2(3345, -4996); //ini curve
var v3 = new THREE.Vector2(4366, -4891); //mid curve
var v4 = new THREE.Vector2(4741, -3597); //end curve
```

Can I get from this created path different other points given a initial point in this path and a distance? For instance, giving v1 and distance 1000 should give a coordinate between v2 and v3.

Comment: You should take a look at [this example](http://threejs.org/examples/#webgl_geometry_extrude_splines) of spline curves and the path they got (turn ON and OFF the Spline Animation View)

Comment: Still I don't see any "new Path" at this example, even some path attributes are being used. From my research it looks like Path is used to later on extrude and get 3D objects such as letters or any other user defined 3D objects.

Answer (score 2):

```
// smooth my curve over this many points
var numPoints = 100;

spline = new THREE.SplineCurve3([
   new THREE.Vector3(0, 0, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(0, 200, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(150, 150, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(150, 50, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(250, 100, 0),
   new THREE.Vector3(250, 300, 0)
]);

var material = new THREE.LineBasicMaterial({
    color: 0xff00f0,
});

var geometry = new THREE.Geometry();
var splinePoints = spline.getPoints(numPoints);

for(var i = 0; i < splinePoints.length; i++){
    geometry.vertices.push(splinePoints[i]);  
}

var line = new THREE.Line(geometry, material);
scene.add(line);
```

Comment: Yes, I'm able to draw curves, even to draw a straight line ending with a nice curve, this is not the question. The problem comes when I want to measure inside this line+curve (that I personally consider a THREE.Path). Let's say I want to know distance inside two points of this line+curve, do I have already tools to measure this at THREE.js? Right now I'm already working on implementing it on my own with some maths.